# What do you use Reactive Extensions for?

Tags: system.reactive

I have a very light grasp of the Rx framework and while I understand some of its capabilities, I'm not sure of where it makes sense to use it, especially in a "real-life" scenario e.g. a distributed Web app.

Do you use Rx? Which version? What for?

Comment: It's a different and mind-bending approach to code that is in response to events. I've found it powerful, for a distributed web application that may include receiving messages or the completion of a download or even user actions.

Comment: Not constructive? Seriously? SO mods at it again. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+do+you+use+

Comment: That list actually helps a lot, as those questions are not constructive either.  Thank you.

Comment: I would have liked to read more answers, too!  :(

Comment: I use it for a quick search feature. I also built a demo : http://blog.andrei.rinea.ro/2013/06/01/bing-it-on-reactive-extensions-story-code-and-slides/